# How to create tensorflow dataset from runtime generated images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So, I start a small project based on tensorflow and could not understand how to prepare dataset generated from memory input.
I have a random number of sources, that generate images. Than I pass it to python script. Images created as bytes array with png format.
I collect images to array, and want to prepare dataset from it and train model based on this dataset.

```
global_feeded_images = []
global_feeded_labels = []


def feed_image(self, img):
    global global_feeded_images
    global_feeded_images.append(bytes(img))
    global_feeded_labels.append(0)
```

After collecting all images, I want to start model training.

```
 model.fit(image_train_ds, np.array(global_feeded_labels), epochs=10)
```

As I understand, tensorflow could accept numpy array or tensor, but I could not understand, what I should convert, each image separatly or whole array?
Or, more shortly, how to convert array of images global_feeded_images to dataset image_train_ds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution was simple.

```
fp = io.BytesIO(bytes(img)) # our bytes array
        with fp:
            im = Image.open(fp)
            im = im.convert('L') # do grayscale or set corrent shape for flatten layer
            numpydata = np.asarray(im) # tf could consume numpy

global_feeded_images.append(numpydata)
global_feeded_labels.append(0)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((global_feeded_images, global_feeded_labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`.

So if your image is a bytes array of PNG/JPG, you'd do something this. You'll have to wrangle the data a bit, but this is the basic idea.

```
global_feeded_images: typing.Sequence[bytes] # Assume python bytes type. 
global_feeded_labels: typing.Sequence[int] # Assume categorical labels

images = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(global_feeded_images, output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=tf.uint8),)

labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(global_feeded_labels, output_signature=(tf.TensorSpece(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int64),)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))

NUM_CLASSES = 777 # or whatever

ds = ds.map(lambda image, label: tf.io.decode_image(image), tf.one_hot(label, NUM_CLASSES)

def resize_image(image:tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
  """Resize per your design here - pad, crop, ignore aspect ratio"""
  return tf.image.resize(image, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))

ds = ds.map(lambda image, label: resize_image(image), label)

BATCH_SIZE = 256 # Or whatever

ds = ds.map(BATCH_SIZE)

ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Note that the docs say that from_generator will not perform well on multi-gpu. In that case, you'll have to go to the effort of writing out TFRecords and reading them in with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`, or, similarly, use the higher level tensorflow_datasets API to create your own custom dataset .

Comment: Still no luck with
 `images = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(global_feeded_images, output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=tf.uint8),)`
I receiving error 
`TypeError: generator must be a Python callable.`

Comment: If I change first argument to function that returns array, I get error   
 `ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 4 for {{node decode_image/DecodeImage}} = DecodeImage[channels=0, dtype=DT_UINT8, expand_animations=true](decode_image/DecodeImage/contents) with input shapes: [1,?,?,?]. `  in 

`ds = ds.map(lambda image, label: (tf.io.decode_image(image), tf.one_hot(label, NUM_CLASSES)))`

string

Comment: I could not even print zipped array, because I get error like this
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: generator yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was (tf.uint8,), but the yielded element was [b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\\r\xa8f\x00\x00 \x00IDATx^\x8c\xbd\xd9\xcem\xc9\xb6\x9d\xf5\xaf\\E\xd6\xbb<\xb6\x84\x00\xfb\x02\t\x9bB\xf6#p\xc9c\xf0\x80\\q\xc9#....`

Comment: Sorry about that, you are experiencing what everyone who'd had to deal with Dataset has found - they are fragile and can be hard to debug. Because the designers of TF wanted very strong typing more akin to C/C++ than Python, when you call from_generator you need to specify the data type. I used tf.uint8, which is wrong. The element is types bytes. Try dtype=tf.string. The truth is, you'll have to fiddle with this data wrangling for a while. It may be easier to break the function out and unit it test it in isolation, Dataset.map() functions run in graph mode which can make debugging harder.